# Where is file located when using "with open"?

Tags: python, filepath

when I write in python this code:

```
with open(FileName, "w") as ans_writer:
    ans_writer.write(ans_table)
```

Where is the `FileName` file saved?

If I don't have such file does it creates it?

How can I change the directory where it saves the file ?

Answer (score 0):

The file will be saved to your working directory, you can get the current working directory with `os.getcwd()`. By default it will be the folder the script is saved in.

Answer (score 0):

Straight from the [manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), which I'd advise you to learn to use:

> *file* is a [path-like object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object) giving the pathname (absolute or relative
> to the current working directory) of the file to be opened or an
> integer file descriptor of the file to be wrapped.

Following the link to see what a "path-like object" is, you find:

> An object representing a file system path. A path-like object is
> either a str or bytes object representing a path, or an object
> implementing the os.PathLike protocol.

You can of course delve into what `os.PathLike` is, but for your uses the first definition probably suffices: `FileName` is a string representing the path to the file in question. `"foo.txt"` refers to the file "foo.txt" in your current working directory. If you don't know what this means, it's likely to be the directory you're in when you run your program. Absolute paths (like `/path/too/somewhere` or `C:\path\to\somewhere`) may be OS-dependent.